# How to extend the prop typings of a native HTML element in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Lets say I have an element that wraps an input and takes all of its properties, in addition to a few more.

In react this would be typed as

```js
interface ExtendedInputProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
    some: Type
}
```

And it's a pretty common use case.  I'm aware that Vue 3 generates its prop types based on whatever is passed to the `props:` object in defineComponent.

I'm imaging doing something like:

```js
props:{
    ...getComponentProps('input')
    additionalProp: String
}
```

But I have no idea how to do that and can't find any docs on it.  Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to do this more for the typescript type checking or so that you don't have to manually/explicitly define all of the second objects properties?

Comment: Yes.  And doesn't vue throw a runtime warning if you pass in an unreconized property?  I'm building components that will be used as part of a library.  The typings and UX need to be good, this can't be a janky interface

Comment: Yeah, I can omit props entirely and set the props type using a type argument/generic on `defineComponent<SomeInterface>` but then Vue seems to block any props from actually reaching my component because they aren't explicitly defined at runtime.

Comment: I don't think you want to declare all of native `input` attributes as wrapper component's props as this would require you to bind them "by hand" in your template or render function. It is better to use a [Non-Prop Attributes](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#non-prop-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest case is when input is the root element of the component, then you don't need to declare anything extra, just pass attributes to your component and they will be passed down

```
//NumberInput Component
<template>
    <input :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
    modelValue?: number
}>(), { modelValue: 0 })
</script>
```

It can be used this way:

```
<number-input v-model="data" type="text" placeholder="123-45-678" />
```

where `type` and `placeholder` will end up as input element's attributes.

If you have input nested inside your component, you need to disable attribute inheritance:

```
//NumberInput Component
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input :value="modelValue" v-bind="$attrs" 
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"  />
  </div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
    modelValue?: number
}>(), { modelValue: 0 })
</script>

<script lang="ts">
// normal `<script>`, executed in module scope (only once)
// declare additional options
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  customOptions: {}
}
</script>
```

Note that we have added second script tag to disable `inheritAttrs` and  added `v-bind="$attrs"` to input to pass attributues down explicitly. More on the  topic you can find out [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

The closest writing may be:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'vue'

interface MyInputProps extends /* @vue-ignore */ InputHTMLAttributes {
  some?: Type
}

defineProps<MyInputProps>()
</script>
```

It works with my `Vue@3.4.8`.